# Boost shared_ptr with typedef struct

Tags: c++, boost, modbus-tcp

I am having compile issues with [libmodbus](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus).  I have the following code

```
boost::shared_ptr <modbus_t> ctx;
ctx->modbus_new_tcp(ip_address.c_str(), modbus_port);
```

but I get the following error

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct _modbus'
```

it points to this line in modbus.h

```
typedef struct _modbus modbus_t;
```

I do not understand enough about this to troubleshoot my problem.  What do you think it is?  Is this library not comptatible with a smart pointer?  They tell you to use a regular pointer

```
modbus_t* ctx;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact this appears to be a C-style API where they've completely hidden the implementation of `modbus_t` from you as a user (since you pass the pointer to free functions rather than calling object members).

What this means is that you can't use `shared_ptr` out of the box (since it needs the definition to call `delete`, which also happens to be the wrong call to make). There *may* be a way to use a custom deleter that calls the appropriate cleanup function (probably `modbus_free`). You would then have to use `.get()` to get the raw pointer any time you wanted to call into the API.

Comment: You definitely *can* use a custom deleter to call whatever function you want.

Answer (score 3):

You could - perhaps - use a

```
if (std::unique_ptr<modbus_t, void(*)(modbus_t*)> mb(modbus_new_tcp(ip_address.c_str(), modbus_port), &modbus_free)) {

    modbus_connect(mb);

    /* Read 5 registers from the address 0 */
    modbus_read_registers(mb, 0, 5, tab_reg);

    modbus_close(mb);
} // modbus_free invoked, even in the case of exception.
```

This, of course, assuming that there is unique ownership.

Comment: Thank you.  I wish c programmers would embrace Boost more

Comment: @xinthose Thank you. I agree, but I'd like to note that nothing is boost-specific in that answer :)